# How to do a `git pull` in several steps

Tags: git, git-pull

I think that a `git pull` command is an alias for a `git fetch` and a `git merge`.

I would like to do a `git pull origin master` in several steps. It think it could be something like this:

```
git fetch origin master
git merge <remote fetched branch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be just simply

```
git fetch origin master
git merge origin/master
```

The first command fetches master from origin. The second merges the remote into your topic branch.

Comment: This assumes that you are on `master` branch

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim, that's incorrect. It doesn't matter what branch you're on.

Comment: The OP actually asked about running git pull when he is in `master` branch. In your answer, you mentioned about topic branch. The command will indeed merge  origin/master to the current branch which is topic branch. And for OP it's `master`.

Answer (score 1):

A `git fetch` update the remote-tracking branches under `refs/remotes/<remote>/`.
So the commands should be:

```
git fetch origin master
git merge refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/1978945) about the difference between `git pull` a `git fetch`.

Comment: See @isherwood answer, `refs/remotes/` is optional.